# Does Netty always close channel if unable to send a message

Tags: java, connection, netty

I am using Netty 4.1. Let's say I have an active netty channel (TCP or SSL) and I write a message to it. The message goes through all of my handlers without a problem. If netty is unable to send this message for any reason, am I guaranteed that the channel will be closed (and close future listener invoked)?

I am trying to see if I can avoid registering a listener for every write and use the voidPromise() optimization:

```
nettyChannel.writeAndFlush(message, nettyChannel.voidPromise());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not. That said if an IOException is thrown from the Socket it will close the Channel.

Comment: What are the possible cases when a message is dropped but the channel remains active? Assume that the ByteBuf is fine. Is there some bounded queue?